# Why read-line reads to symbol (instead of string) in sbcl compiled executable?

Tags: common-lisp, sbcl

Just as an exercise, I am trying to use CL to filter output from the bash `locate` command by directories (i.e. list only files that are directories). For that, I created a file named `dirfilter.lisp` with the following code:

```lisp
#!/usr/bin/env -S sbcl --script

(let (line)
  (loop while (setq line (read-line))
    when (not (pathname-name (probe-file line)))
    do (princ line) (terpri)))
```

It works fine when using it as follows `locate -i hello | ./dirfilter.lisp`.

However, also just as an exercise, I have created a standalone executable by removing the shebang line and then using the following lines from the SBCL repl:

```lisp
(load (compile-file "dirfilter.lisp"))

(save-lisp-and-die "dirfilter" :executable t)
```

Now, however, when trying to use the standalone executable as follows `locate -i hello | ./dirfilter` I get the following error:

```
debugger invoked on a UNBOUND-VARIABLE @52BBE314 in thread
#<THREAD tid=203029 "main thread" RUNNING {1001448003}>:
  The variable /HOME/DALANICOLAI/HELLO.PNG is unbound.
```

As far as I understand the error, read-line in the executable does not read the input as a string but as a symbol.

What is happening here, and how to fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've misdiagnosed the problem.  You need to

- define a function which is your program,
- and tell SBCL to call that function on restart with the `toplevel` argument to `save-lisp-and-die`.

See [the manual](http://www.sbcl.org/manual/#Saving-a-Core-Image).

Without doing this, what it's doing is just starting a REPL which then tries to read a pathname as a symbol and then evaluate that symbol.